# Why does everyone in the universe have a feeling that something's going on that nobody would tell them what it is?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

> "You know," said Arthur thoughtfully, "all this explains a lot of things. All through my life I've had this strange unaccountable feeling that something was going on in the world, something big, even sinister, and no one would tell me what it was." 
>   "No," said the old man, "that's just perfectly normal paranoia. Everyone in the Universe has that."
>    <sub>-THGTTU</sub>

But *why* does everyone have this feeling?

Comment: You don't KNOW?

Comment: because it is "perfectly normal"

Comment: Because six times nine was *supposed* to be forty-two.

Comment: @NKCampbell Much like the beasts, it would seem.

Comment: Are you telling me that you *don't* have perfectly normal paranoia? That makes me suspicious.

Answer (score 4):

Well, one reason might be that there is a vast conspiracy to hide the fact that one man - the Man in the Shack - is really running the whole universe.

Answer (score 2):

Zaphod and a consortium of psychiatrists, including his private brain care specialist, are really running things and being President was just a front.